# Does MySQL support a parameter like "error_on_nondeterministic_update"?

Tags: mysql, sql

The update statement mentioned below should return an error because there are 2 matching values.

```
drop table t1;
drop table t2;

CREATE TABLE t1(x1 int, y1 int);

CREATE TABLE t2(x2 int, y2 int);

INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (1,10), (2,20), (3,30);

INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (2,40), (2,50);

UPDATE t1 as a inner join t2 as b  SET a.y1=b.y2 WHERE a.x1=b.x2;
```

This will update the value of 2 to 40 and will ignore that there is another row with value of 50.
If I get an error, I will know that something is wrong with my join query.

Comment: and so will redshift https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_error_on_nondeterministic_update.html

Comment: As documentation claims, "For the multiple-table syntax, UPDATE updates rows in each table named in table_references that satisfy the conditions. Each matching row is updated once, even if it matches the conditions multiple times." [UPDATE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html). *The update statement mentioned below should return an error* No. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b3e2eaed9209eab03c7b430e97cc9263

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you right , I was wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you write it as subquery , you will get an error

```
UPDATE t1 as a 
SET a.y1=( select b.y2 from t2 as b  WHERE a.x1=b.x2)
```